# Increase or View all Stored History in Gedit

Tags: gedit, history

I would like to be able to see the last ~200 files opened in Gedit. I was able to increase the number it shows to 40 using this command:

```
gconftool-2 --type int --set /apps/gedit-2/preferences/ui/recents/max_recents 40
```

but it is only showing me the last 23. I looked in `.recently-used.xbel` and found that it has only stored the last 23 opened gedit files, as well as files from other applications. Is there a way to increase this? I accept that the last ~200 opened in gedit are no longer stored, but I would like to store them in the future so I can view them. Essentially, can I tell ubuntu to keep ~10X more history in that recently-used.xbel file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_gedit_recent_files_dconf

Make usage of dconf-editor to change the property 'max-recents'.
Under org > gnome > gedit > preferences > ui:

Change the value of max-recents.

It was tested on ubuntu 12.0.4 and 14.04 LTS 64 bits.

In the 2 following screen dumps you can find:

- Where it was configured in dconf-editor
- An example that it works perfectly.

[image]

[image]